# DNS configuration on Ubuntu EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I created an Ubuntu 14.04 server instance on Amazon's EC2
(using AMI - ami-b141a2f5 ) running as a spot instance.

As soon as the instance is launched I can connect from my Mac using SSH to
the elastic ip address.

However, I can't ping google.com or any other URI.
I can't run apt-get, wget, curl, etc.  All commands get 'hostname unresolved'.

I have used elastic ip (linked to VPC), 
Route 53 with a registered domainname and two rulesets:

ns-1620.awsdns-10.co.uk
ns-250.awsdns-31.com
ns-1338.awsdns-39.org
ns-898.awsdns-48.net

VPC with:
DNS Resolution = Yes,
DNS Host Names - Yes,

and an unrestricted security group.

/etc/resolv.conf is empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When running in a proper VPC, [you need to set up an internet gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Wizard.html).

Alternately, [you can run a NAT server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html).

Comment: I followed the instructions for setting up the internet gateway in the link you provided and launched an instance with the new VPC:  ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-139:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com